# Expanding a multi-linear polynomial in the "correct" way

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, expression-manipulation

Let's say I have the formula

```
fmla = x1^2 + (x1 + 1) (x2 + 2)
```

If I `Expand` it, I get:

```
In[1]:=  Expand[fmla]
Out[1]:= 2 + 2 x1 + x1^2 + x2 + x1 x2
```

How can I expand it, so as to get the typical expansion (all linear terms, followed by all quadratic terms, followed by all cubic terms, ..., followed by all interactions)?  That is, I want to get:

```
In[1]:=  MyExpand[fmla]
Out[1]:= 2 + 2 x1 + x2 + x1^2 + x1 x2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is output formating issue, not the expansion itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since summation is commutative, *Mathematica* arranges the terms alphabetically.

You can define a function to return a $k^{th}$ degree term and print them individually (for one's personal visual preference).

I did it like this:

```
fmla = x1^2 + (x1 + 1) (x2 + 2) // Expand

(* The following Module takes the vector components of {x1,x2,x3,...} \
in powers of {i1,i2,i3,...} and multiplies them. *)
M[exp_, x_, i_] := 
 Module[{exp0 = exp, x0 = x, i0 = i}, 
  If[Length[x] == 0, Return[exp0], exp0 = exp x[[1]]^i[[1]]]; 
  x0 = Delete[x, 1]; i0 = Delete[i, 1]; Return[M[exp0, x0, i0]]]

(* The following Module returns the part of the expression which is \
of order k. *)
ORD[func_, k_] := Module[{exp = 0},
  Do[exp = 
    exp + If[Total[c[[1]]] == k, c[[2]] M[1, Variables[func], c[[1]]],
       0], {c, CoefficientRules[func]}];
  Return[exp]]

(* The maximum degree of polynomial: *)
DG = Exponent[fmla /. Table[xi -> x, {xi, VR}], x];

(* The following line prints different parts of the polynomial up to \
the maximum degree. *)
Do[Print["Degree #", i, ": ", ORD[fmla, i]], {i, 0, DG, 1}];
```

The output of the preceding code is:

```
2 + 2 x1 + x1^2 + x2 + x1 x2
Degree #1: 2
Degree #2: 2 x1 + x2
Degree #3: x1^2 + x1 x2
```

If desired, you can always use `ORD[fmla,k]` as a regular expression (derive, integrate, whatever). You can even add several different degrees and use them (keep up to order 2, for example), however, it'll still be arranged alphabetically.

Anyway, *Mathematica* doesn't care about the order of terms and does its job pretty well.